# Cell shows "0" when adding 3 cells containing cell references

Tags: excel

I have 3 cells that contain references from individual columns that are non-adjacent which are to RANK data  from the column single cells. Then, I want to total the three cells in the row. I have used SUM, I have used NUMBERVALUe and I have just added C3 + D3 + F3 (as an example). They are all number formats.

I used the number formats to do SUM; I changed the cells to text and used NUMBERVALUE; I changed back to number and did the above simple example using C3,D3 and F3.

In each case, the cell showed the correct formula in the bar, but "0" for the cell value. If I click the fx button, it shows the correct value for the total. I am at a loss. Suggestions?

Jake

Comment: Did you check the number format of the cell itself?

Comment: Yes, I did. Apologies for omitting that.

Comment: After a bit of digging, I think I need to add some more info. I am using RANK.EQ to obtain cell rankings, one-by-one, of cells within a column. There are a series of columns, all having an extra column to show the ranking for the column to its left.

Then, by row, I want to total the individual rankings to get an overall total for each row. That is where the problem lies. I do note a circular reference error, so I either have to find a remedy, or come up with another plan.